# Establishing DCs for intimidation checks against NPC's other than using the existing Conversation Reaction Table

Tags: dnd-5e, difficulty-class, social-combat, intimidation

### Question Backstory

In the DMG for 5th ed there is established DC levels for how NPC's will respond to you in social interactions based on whether they are friendly, indifferent, or hostile to you as detailed in the Conversations Reactions Table on pg 255 of the DMG.

Conversation Reaction

> DC Friendly Creature’s Reaction
> 0  The creature does as asked without taking risks or making sacrifices.
> 10 The creature accepts a minor risk or sacrifice to do as asked.
> 20 The creature accepts a significant risk or sacrifice to do as asked.
>
> DC Indifferent Creature’s Reaction
> 0  The creature offers no help but does no harm.
> 10 The creature does as asked as long as no risks or sacrifices are involved.
> 20 The creature accepts a minor risk or sacrifice to do as asked.
>
> DC Hostile Creature’s Reaction
> 0  The creature opposes the adventurers’ actions and might take risks to do >so.
> 10 The creature offers no help but does no harm.
> 20 The creature does as asked as long as no risks or sacrifices are involved.

These levels of familiarity seem to be more geared towards determining the DCs for persuasion checks more than they are for determining the DCs for Intimidation checks. This perception is reinforced by the common practice that a failed intimidation check can result in a persuasion check no longer being capable (a DM's interpretation I know, and not one I agree with, but one I have seen at more than one table).

To help in explaining here are the descriptions of the three levels

> Friendly:
> A **Friendly** creature wants to help the adventurers and wishes for them to succeed. For tasks or actions that require no particular risk, effort, or cost, friendly creatures usually help without question. If an element of personal risk is involved, a successful charisma check might be required to convince a friendly creature to take that risk.
>
> Indifferent:
> An **Indifferent** creature might help or hinder the party, depending on what the creature sees as most beneficial. A creature’s indifference doesn’t necessarily make it standoffish or disinterested. Indifferent creatures might be polite and genial, surly and irritable, or anything in between. A successful Charisma check is necessary when the adventurers try to persuade an indifferent creature to do something.
>
> Hostile:
> A **Hostile** creature opposes the adventurers and their goals but doesn’t necessarily attack them on sight. For example, a condescending noble might wish to see a group of upstart adventurers fail so as to keep them from becoming rivals for the king’s attention, thwarting them with slander and scheming rather than direct threats and violence. The adventurers need to succeed on one or more challenging Charisma checks to convince a hostile creature to do anything on their behalf. **That said, a hostile creature might be so ill-disposed toward the party that no Charisma check can improve its attitude,** in which case any attempt to sway it through **diplomacy** fails automatically.

Given this description for the levels, I am going to try to detail a few points of confusion.

1. This is supposed to be for all charisma checks but the easiest to accomplish is when they are friendly. Why would a character intimidate or threaten someone who is friendly to them, and wouldn't that make them no longer friendly, and therefore make it harder?
2. The description for Hostile specifically mentions the word diplomacy in lieu of charisma check, which is not a term I would use to describe intimidation most of the time and lends better to the idea of being persuasive.
3. The description for hostile also indicates that there is a point where a character can become so hostile that no amount of charisma checks could persuade them, however, why would them being hostile prevent them from being subject to intimidation?

### Actual Question

There does not seem to be a rules clarification that could help deal with the issue of how to deal with intimidation checks other than using a system that does not adequately represent them. In this absence, I am seeking judgment from a practiced GM on whether one of two alternatives I have come up with constitute a consistent way for creating DCs for intimidation checks? I am also interested in hearing any alternative ways of dealing with this situation that other GMs have found work.

## Possible Solution 1:

Would it be reasonable to add two more levels to the Conversation Reaction Table with hostile being the center and having persuasion and intimidation work best on opposing sides of the list so that it looks something like:

Friendly
Indifferent
Hostile
Cautious
Afraid

## Possible Solution 2:

Or would it be better to create a separate reaction chart to allow for a character to feel threatened and friendly at the same time as is sometimes possible in reality so that you would have two charts that parallel one another like so:

Friendly|Frightened
Indifferent|Dismissive
Hostile|Amused

## Possible Solution 3:

Or are both of these adjustments too cumbersome to work properly and is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: "usually" is more like a survey than a question with objective answers. Consider changing it to something like "how it should be done by the rules?" or "there are no rules, so what is a balanced and consistent way to rule this?"

Comment: @Mołot Thankyou for the suggestion, will edit now.

Comment: You mention wanting to use the Frightened condition for a successful intimidation in your lead, but not in the body. Is that something you want to see if others have used and to what effect?

Comment: [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73089/22566)

Comment: It appears that you have edited this to include an answer (or a collection of answers) to your question.  It is OK to answer your own question here, so I'd like to recommend that you take the answer portion and make your own answer out of it, and limit your question to the question(s) you have.   The "some alternae suggestions" portion, and down, is for sure more answer than question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast thankyou for your advice. I have mostly increased the detail on this question because I wanted to get it taken off of hold. I am new to the boards and am trying to make the question as clear as possible to keep within the guidelines provided in the introduction and to get the hold status removed.

That said, could you clarify what you mean by "Take the answer portion and make your own answer out of it, and limit your question to the question(s) you have." I am very much interested in receiving advice on how to improve the question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I saw a separate post where the asker marked the introduction as backstory and designated which part was the actual question. This sounded to me like what you might have been getting at, If so I have edited the post to make it more clear and direct.

Comment: Your edit did organize it a lot better, and your "what is the best way forward?" seems to me more focused.  Your point on "diplomacy" being left in there strikes me as a hold over from 3.x where diplomacy was a skill, though in a general usage / plain language reading (how 5e is intended to be read) diplomacy in context of that passage I don't think refers to a skill but to the normal use of that term outside of the game: trying to be diplomatic rather than being forceful.  You can probably sub in the term 'persuasive' and it would fit perfectly.

Comment: This question also doesn't address 'briar-patch' situations, where players goad a hostile character into thinking he is harming the group, when in reality he is helping. Sometimes you just have to play it by ear. Frankly, the whole system is overly complicated. It's much better for me as a GM to think 'How difficult do I think it should be to convince the NPC to do X' and base the check on that rather than on some needlessly complex chart.

Comment: @MarkTO I never liked that way of doing things, As a player, I want to know that there is a hard sheet, a definite number that the GM is using as a base rather than what otherwise amounts to a whim, and as a GM I bring that preference with me.
It takes a bit of finessing and extra work, but I very much prefer having a set system to use when deciding how hard things should be for my players, in the same way, I would want my GM to use one when I am a player. 
Plus you can't really get rid of concepts like Friendly, indifferent, hostile or it makes spells that mention them pointless.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That interpretation of "diplomacy" was mine as well, which is why it surprised me when it said it after saying that charisma checks just wouldnt work any more at a certain level of hostility, because surely persuasion wouldnt work any more but intimidation would.

Comment: @PeterSaba I get that. One of the other players in my campaign feels much the same way, all the way to the point of objecting to homebrew or reskinning because it deviates from the material. (What do you mean, Radiant Servant of Osiris! The book says Pelor, so it has to be Pelor!) I just find that if the end result is indistinguishable to a player,it frees up time and energy to put into story and setting. But if we all played the same, it wouldn't be such a rich hobby. And those mechanical terms in my freeform style become general descriptors, not hard categories.

Comment: @MarkTO I understand, Homebrew and reskinning is actually something that I am very fond of, so you won't find me begrudging you on that. but as for the mechanical terms becoming just descriptors, I have to be honest that is where I would be frustrated and I'd understand your player's feelings. When I first started playing 5E last year I had no prior experience with DnD so seeing these terms and trying to figure out what they mean or how they affect my bard was maddening until I found them defined in the DMG. And I only ended up finding them because I was trying to homebrew something LOL.

Comment: @PeterSaba I would honestly add the restriction that you don't want systems that depend on DM-fiat (or however you might better say it) in detail, because it seems like most of the answerers do not realize this.

Comment: Have we made too many adjustments to this question that it now invalidates the answers?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose by GM fiat do you mean the GM just deciding what makes sense to them without guidelines? Becasue yes maybe I do need to add that clarification.

Comment: @NautArch Could you explain what you mean by the edits to the question invalidating the answer? Admitably the three answers I got so far were before I made the edits because the question was said to be confusing, which I can see because all 3 answers say to use wisdom save and one of them say to just use the normal table which I explicitly said didn't make sense to do in the original question.
Perhaps at this point It might be better to just restart the question from scratch but I don't know if that is allowed.

Comment: @PeterSaba Mostly that we have answers currently below and if your question adds their answers into it and then asks something new, then it invalidates them - which is something we try not to do. If you are fixing your question and it fundamentally means the answers aren't valid anymore, it may be better to ask it anew.

Comment: @NautArch is that allowed? would I need to delete this question before asking a the new one and is it ok to just cut and paste the text I currently have for this question into the new ask? Honestly, the answers for this have stalled completely and I think I was hurt by the day and a half it spent on hold so I am more than willing to breath new life into it.

Answer (score 2):

The general guideline for ability checks (PHB p. 174) give DC's ranging from Very easy (DC 5) up-to Nearly impossible (DC 30). For any given NPC set the DC corresponding to how difficult they are to scare (generally related to their Wisom score).

Alternately you could call it as a contest; either Charisma (Intimidation) against Charisma (Intimidation) for two creatures each trying to be the scariest, or Charisma (Intimidation) against Wisdom (Insight) for the "defending" creature trying to ascertain how genuine the threats are.

---

At my table we use intimidation as a contest between a Charisma (Intimidation) check against the targets Wisdom saving throw. The idea being a wisdom saving throw represents the creatures ability resist influence on their mind.

Comment: So it is easier to intimidate a Fighter than a Wizard?

Comment: @András wizards are generally intelligent rather than wise.

Comment: @DaleM my point exactly, Wisdom saves have no correlation with intimidatability

Comment: Also Insight has the problem that if a succesful check shows you the intimidating party _is_ a genuine threat, you should be _more_ intimidated, not _less_.

Comment: It's easier to intimidate fighter than priest, by this answer. Makes sense, as in "my faith is my shield and I fear not" stories found in mythologies and real holy texts. Wizards and fighters both don't have particular need for Wis anyway so are equally "scareable".

Comment: @Mołot, I agree they _should be_ equally scareable, except Wizards (and Warlocks) add their prof bonus to their Wis saves. So a Wis save is a bad target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91558/discussion-between-nautarch-and-someone-evil).

Comment: [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73089/22566)

Answer (score 2):

The DC will generally be up to the DM, based on how scared/resolved/etc he feels the NPC is likely to be.

The basic rules suggest typical difficulty levels for any ability check (which would include social interactions) [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#TypicalDifficultyClasses)

> Very easy=DC 5
>
> Easy=DC 10
>
> Medium=DC 15
>
> Hard=DC 20
>
> Very hard=DC 25
>
> Nearly impossible=DC 30

Alternatively, the DM could make it a contested check as explained a bit further down in the link above. The DM would compare the player's Intimidation check against some check of the NPC (a straight Wisdom check, a Wisdom(Insight) perhaps or whatever the DM feels is appropriate for the situation).

Answer (score -2):

According to the DMG:

> a successful Charisma check might be required to convince a friendly
>   creature to take that risk, A successful Charisma check is necessary
>   when the adventurers try to persuade an indifferent creature to do
>   something, and The adventurers need to succeed on one or more
>   challenging Charisma checks to convince a hostile creature to do
>   anything on their behalf

(see pg. 244 of the DMG, these are parts of each of the entries on friendly, indifferent, and hostile creatures). According to these, since intimidation is a charisma check, the npc could likely either use a charisma or a wisdom DC.

Another option is to simply choose a target DC. (Very easy=DC 5, Easy=DC 10, Medium=DC 15, Hard=DC 20, Very hard=DC 25, Nearly impossible=DC 30, see DMG 238). When you do this, the PC simply makes a skill check (in this case, intimidation), and if it is above the target's DC, then it succeeds (NOT a contest).

Another way to do this is to simply determine how well they succeed based on their charisma roll, here's an example (see pg. 245 DMG)

> **Conversation Reaction**
>
> **DC Friendly Creature's Reaction**
>
> 0 The creature does as asked without taking risks or making
>   sacrifices.
>
> 10 The creature accepts a minor risk or sacrifice to do as asked.
>
> 20 The creature accepts a significant risk or sacrifice to do as
>   asked.
>
> **DC Indifferent Creature's Reaction**
>
> 0 The creature offers no he lp but does no harm .
>
> 10 The creature does as as ked as long as no risks or sacrifices are
>   involved.
>
> 20 The creature accepts a minor risk or sacrifice to do as asked.
>
> **DC Hostile Creature's Reaction**
>
> 0 The creature opposes the adventurers' actions and might take risks
>   to do so.
>
> 10 The creature offers no help but does no harm.
>
> 20 The creature does as asked as long as no risks or sacrifices are
>   involved.

Basically, you can have a set DC value that a PC has to overcome, the PC must win a contest with the NPC (see pg. 174 of the Player's Handbook), or the result can depend on how well or poorly the PC's roll goes.

Hope these can be useful!

Comment: "the npc could likely either use a charisma or a wisdom DC" this is very confusingly worded. Did you mean the DM should set a DC for the NPC for an ability check from the PC? Also how do you get to CHA or WIS for intimidation from CHA for persuasion?

Comment: Yes, and persuasion in the context of the quote means any skill being used to persuade someone (Persuasion, Intimidation, Deception). Basically I'm saying that the DM should set a DC, and saying what stats could be used to determine that DC in the case of a contest situation, with wisdom referring mainly to insight.

Comment: I think the confusion is that when you say one side "sets a DC" and the other beats it, you're talking about a contested ability check and not a DC/Save scenario.

Comment: I mean, the DM chooses a DC value for each NPC in advance (or comes up with it on the spot), and the PC has to roll against that, instead of the DM rolling for the NPC, and the player rolling for the PC, as in a contest

Comment: @Smart_TJ oh I see, well contests do not use a DC. It's an opposed check. So if that is what you are talking about I would clarify the wording there.